# how to style navigation sub-menu?

Tags: theming, routes, navigation

I need to display dash (-) in front of each sub-menu element. For example, the output should be

```
<ul class="menu clearfix">
  <li class="first leaf"><a title="" href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="expanded active-trail"><a class="active-trail active" title="" href="/about-us">About</a>
  <ul class="menu clearfix">
     <li class="first leaf"><a title="" href="/process">- Process</a></li>
     <li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/process-101">- Process 101</a></li>
     <li class="last leaf"><a title="" href="/compnay">- Compnay</a></li>
  </ul></li>
  <li class="last leaf"><a href="/content/useful-links">Useful Links</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I tried the following:

```
function theme_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
     $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
   }

   $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
   return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
  }
```

Comment: So you would like to display the dash *only* in front of a sub-menu element, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with CSS

```
ul.menu ul.menu li a:before {
  content: "- ";
}
```

Or, you can do something similar with `list-style-image` or a `background-image`.

Keeping stuff like that out of markup makes things cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for advice, but IE7 doesn't support content property. Is there an alternate way to do it? Does drupal offer templates for navigation?

Comment: The typical way is to add some `padding-left` to the `li` and then add a `background-image` attached `left center`.  Take a look at http://paulirish.com/2011/tiered-adaptive-front-end-experiences/ for a good read on having to have an identical experience in all browsers.